# Trigger in SQL Server 2012 compare and update

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, sql-update, database-trigger

I want to implement a trigger in SQL Server 2012 where when the update query is fired to a column of a table, the existing value in that particular column should be compared with the new value.

If the new value is greater then only the table should get updated or else not.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below approch:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_For_Update1
ON TableName
FOR UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @n_OldValue int,
            @n_NewValue int

    SELECT
        @n_OldValue = b.ValuesYouCompare, 
        @n_NewValue = a.ValuesYouCompare   -- Update  Old and New values
    FROM 
        inserted a, deleted b

    IF @n_NewValue > @n_OldValue
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Transaction Error'
        ROLLBACK TRAN   -- Roll Back the transaction if condition is not valid
    END
END
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statement that causes this trigger to fire updates 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT ... FROM Inserted i` - it's **non-deterministic**, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged